# How do I log in to 12.04 when after a recent update it no longer recognises my password?

Tags: 12.04, updates

Since carrying out an update yesterday I am now unable to log in. On entering my password the screen goes black momentarily then returns to the log-in screen. If I intentionally enter an incorrect password the text boxes turn red. I can log in normally to a console with ctrl+alt+F1.

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is no problem with your password, I think you X server has a problem.